# Why are characters of $R(\hat G) \otimes \mathbb{C}$ indexed by semisimple conjugacy classes in $\hat{G} (\mathbb{C})$?

Tags: representation-theory

I am reading [Gross notes](http://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Egross/preprints/sat.pdf), and a central fact used there is the following (see (6.1) in the notes): the characters of the representation ring $R(\hat G) \otimes \mathbb{C}$ are indexed by semisimple conjugacy classes in the dual group $\hat G(\mathbb{C})$. I do not make sense of this statement, even in simple cases as $GL_2$.

The correspondence appears to be explicit, $\omega_s (\chi_\lambda) = \chi_\lambda(s)$, but I do not understand what is $\chi_\lambda$ (the "character of the representation" $V_\lambda$, or its trace). Given a representation, who is the semisimple conjugacy class attached to it?